# How to add or remove header.links in magento2?

Tags: magento2, header, magento-2.0.7, toplinks

I am searching **header.links** block to remove one link and add some links but I am **not getting where to make changes**. Suggest me some solution

Comment: In this same custom links, how can I add the custom class?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155567)

Answer (score 25):

I Hope this is useful for you,

if you want to **remove** top.links

Add **default.xml** file in this path

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
        <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
            <body>

                    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
                    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
                    <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
                    <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->

            </body>
        </page>
```

if you want to **add** Custom top links:

go to **app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
        <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
            <body>
            <referenceBlock name="header.links">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">custom link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">customlink</argument>
                </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>

            </body>
        </page>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer how to add custom links and change the label of link

Comment: How to add some design for the custom link which added in the header? @Rajkumar .E

Answer (score 9):

You can add and remove top links by add this line in your in **Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="new.link" after="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">New Link</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">newlink</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>

    <!-- here you can remove whatever link you feel unwanted -->
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
    <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
    <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: How can I remove compare link in `header.links`

Comment: i have created custom links in header, how to move into after logo @Bilal Usean

Answer (score 1):

To add a Toplink in your website header, create a custom module and then follow this:

**Method#1 Basic link using layout XML**

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="whatsapp-link" before="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact us on Whatsapp</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">some-path-url-string</argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-whatsapp</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                    <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>       
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

By just using this file, you will be able to create a custom top link, and with the added class you can style it in you css/less files.

**Method#2 Using Template phtml file** Sometimes there are requirements when you need more control over newly added toplinks, or add image or write your own html. For adding a custom toplink using a template, follow this way.

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="whatsapp-link" template="Namespace_Modulename::whatsappLink.phtml">
            </block>       
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And then add the template phtml file defined in xml above in your code as follow.

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/whatsappLink.phtml
<li class="link whatsapp-link">
    <a href="some-path-url-string" title="Connect via Whatsapp" target="_blank">
        <img class="whatsapp-img" src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Namespace_Modulename::images/WhatsApp_logo.png'); ?>' alt="Whatsapp Image">
        <span class="whatsapp-label">Connect via Whatsapp</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Using this way, I added my icon with toplink and I can play with it as per requirement.

**To remove header link**

```
// app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />        
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rajkumar .E - answered this question and i just want to add that if you need to add custom class add this argument:

```
<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">customclass</argument>
```