# Customize magento 2 theme

Tags: magento2, phtml, header, toplinks

I installed magento 2 and successfully implemented custom theme.

I used magento blank as my theme's parent theme. I'm new to magento, so this may seem like a stupid question, but please help me without actually down-voting or locking this question.

My problem is, how do I change the storefront look in my theme? All I get is usual Magento 2 page with only my logo in it.

- How do I edit header section?
- Which files I may need to edit or add?
- I need to edit top links section (usually contains links like sign in, my account, register)?

Please help.

Comment: nobody can help me? nothing? :(

Comment: take a look here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html i know the magento dev.docs is not the best source, but you can find some useful information there. also this might help with your question about editing the top links. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138357/how-to-add-or-remove-header-links-in-magento2 . generally I would recommend you to read to tutorials and articles about custom theme developing, e.g. http://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html All info you need will be here

Copy `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml` to you theme directory `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml` (path will same in magento_theme)
This will override original by your template header when your theme loaded

Add new link to top. Put this code to anyfile layout in your theme. This block `top.links` only exist in theme-blank

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link"  name="test-link" after="-" cacheable="false">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">test-link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for you take time for my question. im not little bit unclear on last part of the answer. Do I need to put above code into my header.phtml file or in some xml file? im not clear on adding stuff. heard there are 2 ways of adding data into magento theme. one is using backend and linking to phtml files and other one is not using backend but use only xml and phtml files. this is the place Im stuck at..
Sorry if I make this worse

Comment: it depends on your requirement. But i think layout way will help you for common demands

Comment: you mean with xml editing right? thing is I have very low knowledge on how to do that. magento devdocs are not helpful. if you can please help me with that.. i need something to learn how to customize theme with xml files and backend. i searched google,a lot. but still couldn't find something good