# Header.links magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2.2.3

I was trying to add this solution [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138357/how-to-add-or-remove-header-links-in-magento2) but it's only removing links but without adding new ones. My parent theme is Blank theme, so I use header.links (not top.links)

Edited file app/design/frontend/Myvendorname/Mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="new.link" after="register-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">New Link</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">newlink</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>

<!-- here you can remove whatever link you feel unwanted -->
<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
<referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
<referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
<referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution. I just change position of one  plus I change panel.links to header.panel. Panel.links class is inside header.panel.

and code that I put inside  app/design/frontend/Myvendorname/Mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.panel">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="new.link" after="register-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Contact</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact</argument>

    </arguments>
</block>
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="new.link2" after="new-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">About Us</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">about-us</argument>

    </arguments>
</block>
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="new.link3" after="new-link2">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Customer Support</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">customer-support</argument>

    </arguments>
</block>

    </referenceBlock>

    <!-- here you can remove whatever link you feel unwanted -->
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
    <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
    <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
    <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->


    </body>
    </page>
```

Helpful link from Magento2 documentation [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)