# How can I remove b2b module links in the header?

Tags: b2b, magento2.2.6

I have made a child theme off Luma and am on 2.2.6. Company Structure, Requisition Lists, and Send Invitations are all links on the drop down in the header. I tried this- [How to add or remove header.links in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138357/how-to-add-or-remove-header-links-in-magento2) and it works for other links but not these b2b links. How can I find the name to remove or is there a different way?

Comment: Have you got solution?

Comment: Nope, I still have not been able to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code.

Add default.xml file in below path.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

For remove Requisition Lists link add below code.

```
<referenceBlock name="requisition.list.link" remove="true"/>
```

For remove company Structure link add below code.

```
<referenceBlock name="company.link" remove="true"/>
```

For remove send Invitations link add below code.

```
<referenceBlock name="invitation_link_top" remove="true"/>
```

Then don't forgot to run below command.

> php bin/magento c:c
>
> php bin/magento c:f